# Array keys being sorted incorrectly by 'uksort()' function

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key

I have an array whose keys are in the format [A1] -> [A20], [B1] -> [B20], etc, and I'm trying to sort that array using first `ksort()` (to get the letters in the correct order) and then `uksort()`.

However, I can't figure out how the `uksort()` function should be written, and my array keys are coming back in a weird order. Could someone please take a look and advise as to what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
function _sort_selection_keys($a, $b){

    $let_a = substr($a, 0, 1);
    $let_b = substr($b, 0, 1);
    $num_a = intval(substr($a, 1));
    $num_a = intval(substr($b, 1));

    /** Check that the first letter is the same. It should be, as the array has already been through 'ksort()', but it's worth checking any way */
    if($let_a !== $let_b) :
        return strcasecmp($a, $b);
    endif;

    if($num_a > $num_b) :
        return -1;
    elseif($num_a = $num_b) :
        return 0;
    elseif($num_a < $num_b) :
        return 1;
    endif;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use the ***[strnatcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php)*** function which will fit your needs:

```
uksort($array, 'strnatcmp');
```

And another solution metioned by @M8R-1jmw5r

`ksort($array, SORT_NATURAL);`

Comment: Why not just: `ksort($array, SORT_NATURAL);`?

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was unaware you could use `uksort()` in that way, but now I see it, it's pretty obvious!

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation for `usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

That is, instead of returning `true` or `false`, you should return `$num_a - $num_b` (or do the comparison and return `-1`, `1`, or `0`.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is easier to understand than the one in the docs!

Answer (score 1):

First, I think all you need to do is change your second "$num_a" line to "$num_b".
Other than that, I would simply use strnatcasecmp() on the keys instead of all the dissecting you are attempting.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of that function, and it did work. However the answer from @xdazz eliminated the need for me to use a custom callback, so I'm going to accept his answer.

Comment: AS usual, almost always a few different ways to skin the cat!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Without debugging your code there, you can use built-in functionality of the [`uksort`](http://php.net/uksort) to sort keys alphanumerically with 'strnatcmp'.

**Unsorted Array Code**

```
$array = array(
    'A1' => array(),
    'A2' => array(),
    'A3' => array(),
    'A4' => array(),
    'C1' => array(),
    'B2' => array(),
    'B1' => array(),
    'D1' => array(),
    'C2' => array(),
    'B3' => array(),
    'D3' => array(),
    'D2' => array(),
);

uksort($array, 'strnatcmp');

var_dump($array);
```

**Result**

```
array (size=12)
  'A1' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'A2' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'A3' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'A4' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'B1' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'B2' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'B3' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'C1' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'C2' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'D1' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'D2' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'D3' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the example, that is indeed what I did (but @xdazz got there just before you).

Comment: @DavidGard Such is life. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to sort your array by the keys in *natural order*:

```
ksort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
```

See [`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort).

Natural sort order is:

```
regular:  A1, A10, A11, A2, A20, A21, ... A3, ...
natural:  A1, A2, A3, ..., A10, A11, ... A20, A21
```

Comment: Thanks, but not quite. It sorts the number element naturally, but the letters at the start of the key are left in the original order.

Comment: @DavidGard: You then should see the exact problems with `strnatcmp()`. The solution then is the padded sort I linked in the comment above.

Comment: Nope, that one is working fine. For example if original order is `E5, E1, E10, A5, A1, A10`, `ksort($array, SORT_NATURAL)` orders it `E1, E5, E10, A1, A5, A10`, where as `uksort($array, 'strnatcmp')` is ordering it `A1, A5, A10, E1, E5, E10`.

Comment: I can not reproduce, see the example: http://3v4l.org/pn5QO (or yours: http://3v4l.org/3rXAA) - Maybe you get a different result because of the PHP version? `SORT_NATURAL` is PHP 5.4.

Comment: Perhaps. I'm heading home now, but will try and have a look tomorrow and post back. It does seem odd that it would sort it that way, but unless my monitor is playing a late April fools on me, that's what it did.

Comment: @DavidGard: You don't need to look further. PHP sourcecode reveals that using the `SORT_NATURAL` flag will use the same internal comparison function as if you use `strnatcmp()` as a callback function. If you're using PHP 5.4 (or target that version), I would prefer ksort over uksort. But both behave identical. Check the sort functions return value if you want to find out that the sort flag was used or not: http://codepad.org/ndubGuxH (returns FALSE if the flag is not available, most likely the case in your scenario). HTH. HF.

Comment: Well I've had a look and I'm running version 5.3.3, which the Changelog tells me is before `SORT_NATURAL` was introduced. Thanks for helping with the investigation here!